# Issues with cron

Tags: unix, ubuntu, cron

I'm really stuck. I've used cron on many machines, but I simply can not get it to work on an Ubuntu server. I've tried everything I can think over the weekend and I'm baffled. I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I can verify that cron is running via `pgrep cron`. However, `pgrep crond` returns nothing. I am trying to run a simple shell script (test.sh) with cron:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/touch /home/jarvis/test.txt
```

I have run `chmod +x` on the shell script and my crontab looks like this:

```
01 * * * * /home/jarvis/test.sh
```

I also have a new line ending after the line.

Comment: Maybe this belongs here: http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: I also tried the same command on Red Hat and it also does not work, so I think the problem is not Ubuntu specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting all output to a file and see if there are any error messages that can help you diagnose the problme, i.e.

```
01 * * * * /home/jarvis/test.sh > /tmp/jarvis_test.log 2>&1
```

Also, if you created any of those files from a windows environment, don't forget  `dos2unix filename`

**edit**
My point is that you won't know for what your script is doing in the crontab environment unless you see if it is outputing an error message. Error messages also go to local crontab user's email, so try `mail` (as the same user) and see if you have a bunch of messages from your crontab.

---

`pgrep crond` returning nothing sounds like the problem, but I'm not a sysadmin. Maybe you want to flag this and ask for moderator to move to https://serverfault.com/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can run `./test.sh` and the command works as it should, ie. a new file named test.txt is create. I'm not sure how your command should work. Can you redirect a cron to a log file?

Comment: TMy example is a cron entry. note that it is the same as your cmd except for the redirection at the end. Also, see edits.

Comment: Ok, I think we are getting somewhere now. When I follow your advice I get: `0 zsh: command not found: 01`

Comment: Is the leading 0 on a separate line? How are you using cron? Do you know how to use a Unix Editor (vi or emacs) OR are MS windows hosted editor involved? Do you normally use zsh? (That's a surprise seeing that). Good luck.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I accidentally copied the leading line number (I use Vim). I'm still having trouble with cron. Thanks for your help, if I figure out the problem, I'll post it here.

Comment: consider adding `echo $- ; set -o ; set; export` at the top of your script on working and no-working systems to 'dump' the environments from each system, then compare working vs. non-working. Do you accept that your crontab is using zsh as its base shell, that's not typical (as you probably know). Good luck.

Comment: Bingo. zsh is always my default shell and I've never had any trouble using it with cron on another systems. Apparently, on Ubuntu it's a problem. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad that helped. Keep on debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the user permissions. Try putting in default crontab hourly,weekly files, if it works there then your cron is good. Also, check /var/log/messages for any cron entry. View /etc/crontab for detailed configuration.