# DVD Slideshow not creating video and xml while running as cron job

Tags: php, shell, cron, putty

I am using dvdslidshow to create video using images. I run the code from putty as root user as `php filename.php` and the files getting created.

But when I set the same function as cron job video not getting created. Found this error when I log the cron job output.

```
cat: write error: Broken pipe
```

Can Someone suggest what may be the issues? I am providing the command below:

```
shell_exec("/home/nosnowna/public_html/cpanel-2013/community_group/dvd-slideshow-0.8.4-2/dvd-slideshow -o /home/nosnowna/public_html/cpanel-2013/community_group/youtube/ -f /home/nosnowna/public_html/cpanel-2013/community_group/youtube/video_list_215013307.txt");
```

Comment: There are many many articles here on S.O. about debugging `cron` problems. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485689/issues-with-cron/10486193#10486193 will help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks,But I was not able to solve the issue with those articles.I  contacted the server provider and they are working on the issue for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Problem.Edited shell commands in dvd slideshow, its worked.There where issues with ffmpeg also.Its used to convert video created using dvd slideshow.